# Google Weather Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm using regular expressions in PHP to parse the weather results that Google provides when querying 'weather in '.

Basically, I've managed to match every detail I require (humidity, wind, location name, etc) but I simply cannot match the current temperature in Celsius. Is anyone able to provide an expression which would match this?

`<td style="font-size:140%;white-space:nowrap;vertical-align:top;padding-right:15px;font-weight:bold" rowspan=2>10°C | <a href="/setprefs?fheit=1&amp;sig=0_vpPSh_He8v7GXjLf7MhO-wNqNOU=&amp;prev=http://www.google.com/search%3Fq%3Dweather%2Bin%2Bwellington&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=3KVZUL6JMcWsiAfug4GQBQ&amp;ved=0CB8QwwQ" class="fl">&deg;F</a>`

Sorry for the long paste, but the 10 degrees Celsius is near the start. Those are the two HTML tags that wrap around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this? :

```
/>-?(\d+)°C\b/
```